# To Generate and Scan QR code using Zxing without installing Barcode Scanner app in Android Studio

Tags: android, barcode, qr-code, zxing

I want to generate the QR code of my data and then scan the same generated QR code by using the same app.I am trying to import Zxing library as a module in my app.But the classes in core.jar file is not compiled in my root project.It gives the error 'Cannot resolve symbol BarcodeFormat'.
Can anyone please let me know how can I resolve the dependencies?

What is the exact way to integrate Zxing library so that I can implement both functionalities in same app?

Comment: try to add it as dependence from repository, not as jar file, add this `compile 'com.google.zxing:core:2.0'` to your gradle file

Comment: By using this,how can I scan the QR code without installing Barcode Scanner app?I need to use com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity.class to scan QR code.But it can't be resolved using this dependency.

Comment: if you want to use the activity i think you have to add this too, `compile 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.2.0@aar'`